# html & javascript to make a graphical counter

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to tick off days of certian events, and mark their "streak" - and I want to represent them as squares or circles on a table

As an example "Sunny days" vs. "Cloudy Days"

each COLUMN would count the occurrence of an event, and a change of event would move to the next COLUMN.. Sequences would progress UP (or down) by row.

example - table 5 rows x 10 columns (S = sunny, C = cloudy)
Just using javascript - using two buttons, "s" and "c" how would I tell the dom which cell to mark next.

start form blank - click "s" an s goes in the first cell, click "s" and an s goes in the first col second row, click "c" (and because it's a change from last run of days) a c goes in the second col first row... so in short, if the current click is the same as the last, you progress a row, if it's different, you progress a column... and in this regard, it shouldn't be just 2, I could have 3 or 4 "types" of occurrences (like Rain or Snow).

would i just put it all in an array: [s,s,s,s,c,c,s,s,s,s,c,s,c,s,c,c,c,c]

add each event to the array, then loop the array, changing when current!=last ???

but how do I reference the 'correct' table cell?????

```
<table border="1" width="460" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>S</td>
        <td>S</td>
        <td>S</td>
        <td>S</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>S</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>S</td>
        <td>S</td>
        <td>S</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, see `:nth-child(n)`.

Comment: is this strictly JS or would jQuery and/or PHP be acceptable?

Comment: @jpmyob `$("tr:first:nth-child(3)")` would select the third child of the first `tr`.

Comment: @Mooseman I think he would like them to be created dynamically

Comment: @Mooseman and verbum - yes, i'd need a way to tell what the last one was. So in Moosemans example, say I just marked the 3rd cell in row 1... on the next click HOW would I know that? I'll have to think and test, but you've put me on a path.

Comment: @verbum - jquery is fine, but not PHP, I'm trying to do this all client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The pieces

The key here is keeping track of

1. The current object
2. The past object
3. The current cell

Each corresponding to one variable. While you are looping, increment these variables as necessary.
For example, if the current object is not the same as the past object (a broken streak), then you have to change the past object into the current object and then move on:

```
if (current !== past) {
    past = current;
}
```

So that's a start.

Now, you have to keep track of the current cell. Let's use a JS object to define the row and column. Since we start at row 1, column 1, we'll set the default to:

```
var cell = {
    "row": 1,
    "col": 1
}
```

Now, you have to increment the row and column according to the streak. If the streak is extended, then you have to increment the row. If the streak is broken, you have to increment the column **and also set the row back to 1**:

```
if (current !== past) {
    past = current;

    // Increment the column and reset the row
    cell.col++;
    cell.row = 1;
} else {
    // Increment row
    cell.row++;
}
```

Now, we have to place the object into the correct cell. We'll use jQuery's CSS-like selectors to do this. In particular, the `:nth-child(...)` selector is useful here.
This selector simply selects the n-th numbered child inside of a parent. For example, `td:nth-child(2)` will select the second `td` inside of its parent.

Implementing this is fairly easy since we already have the `cell` object:

```
$('table tr:nth-child(' + cell.row + ') td:nth-child(' + cell.col + ')').html(current);
```

`.text(current)` is also usable here, but it only accepts plain text.

### Putting it all together

We'll use `array` as the definition of the array of weather events:

```
var array = [s, s, s, s, c, c, s, s, s, s, c, s, c, s, c, c, c, c];
```

Of course, we use a `for` loop to run through the array:

```
var s = "s",
    c = "c",
    array = [s, s, s, s, c, c, s, s, s, s, c, s, c, s, c, c, c, c],
    cell = {
        "row": 1,
        "col": 1
    };

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    var current = array[i],
        past;

    // Catch the initial state
    if (i === 0) {
        past = current;
        $('table tr:nth-child(' + cell.row + ') td:nth-child(' + cell.col + ')').html(current);
    } else {
        past = array[i - 1];
        if (current !== past) {
            past = current;
            // Increment the column and reset the row
            cell.col++;
            cell.row = 1;
        } else {
            // Increment row
            cell.row++;
        }

        $('table tr:nth-child(' + cell.row + ') td:nth-child(' + cell.col + ')').html(current);
    }

}
```

---

**JSFiddle**:
http://jsfiddle.net/kTsEx/3/

Comment: How INCREDIBLY excellent!!! thank you so much Albert. I love that you explained it through the process.... thank you so much.